# How to join a table as a comma separated string?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, solr

So this is my query as of now:

```
SELECT *, 
JOIN users u 
JOIN user_addresses ua ON u.id = ua.userId_fk 
JOIN timeSlots ts ON u.id = ts.userId_fk
```

I use this in Solr to index users. The timeslots look like this:

```
ID | userId_fk | dayOfWeek | startTime | endTime 
1    100         MONDAY      10:00       12:00
```

How can I join this timeslots data as a comma separated list or something similar, so that I can parse it into a JavaScript object?

Example of desired output:

```
id | address | userName | timeslots
1    123 ave   someName   MONDAY,10:00,12:00 TUESDAY,12:00,18:00
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by joining as a comma separated list...  What *exactly* are you trying to do?

Comment: What  are you using to execute the mysql?  You should be able to use PHP (or ASP, or whatever), to just dump the results into a string.

Comment: Hopefully that "desired output" never makes it into a table

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help

```
    SELECT u.id , ua.address , userName , timeslots, concat(dayOfWeek, ',' ,startTime, ',' ,endTime ) timeslots
    JOIN users u 
    JOIN user_addresses ua ON u.id = ua.userId_fk 
    JOIN timeSlots ts ON u.id = ts.userId_fk
```

You also can group_concat it. if you want to combine multiple timeslots with space separated

```
    SELECT u.id , ua.address , userName , timeslots, group_concat(concat(dayOfWeek, ',' ,startTime, ',' ,endTime ) separator ' ') as timeslots
    JOIN users u 
    JOIN user_addresses ua ON u.id = ua.userId_fk 
    JOIN timeSlots ts ON u.id = ts.userId_fk
    group by userName
```

Answer (score 0):

For mysql you can use 
[GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)